# Complexity of unique coloring of graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, complexity-classes

The [Isolation lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_lemma) of Mulmuley, Vazirani, and Vazirani  can be used to show that certain $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problems can be reduced via randomized polytime reductions to the *unique* solution version of the problem. This hints that  the promise of a unique solution is not likely to make the problem significantly easier.

A specific example for such a reduction in the Mulmuley, Vazirani, and Vazirani paper [(pdf)](http://cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/pubs/matching.pdf)
 is that CLIQUE can be reduced to UNIQUE CLIQUE via randomized polynomial time reductions. In this sense,  UNIQUE CLIQUE is (almost) as hard as CLIQUE.

> Is there anything similar known about the UNIQUE $k$-COLORABILITY of graphs?

It is worth noting that the promise of unique colorability seems to involve more structural consequences than the uniqueness of the maximum clique.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439750400115X

Comment: Thank you, the linked paper provides an interesting answer.

Comment: @AndrasFarago From the reference so $PLAN-3-COL$ problems are essentially to distinguish $3$ colorability from $4$ colorability since we have a parsimonious reduction?

Comment: @AustinBuchanan: Post as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [paper by Régis Barbanchon](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439750400115X) might be of interest. From the abstract:

> We prove that the Satisfiability (resp. planar Satisfiability) problem
> is parsimoniously P-time reducible to the 3-Colorability (resp. Planar
> 3-Colorability) problem, that means that the exact number of solutions
> is preserved by the reduction, provided that 3-colorings are counted
> modulo their six trivial color permutations. In particular, the
> uniqueness of solutions is preserved, which implies that Unique
> 3-Colorability is exactly as hard as Unique Satisfiability in the
> general case as well as in the planar case...